# What's a good log viewer for e.g. apache, postfix, syslog?

Tags: log-files, logging, reporting

Various processes log in various formats to various locations with various roll-over logic in `/var/log`.

I'd like a log-viewer that can handle a decent quantity of data, join roll-over log files, and ideally could even interleave log records to get a timeline of what happened on the machine.

For example, I saw a CPU usage spike at a certain time this morning and I'd like to see if there's anything in any of the logs that explains it.

P.S. Yes I realize there's configuration issues like Apache logs can be "anything" so you'd need to tell the log viewer how to parse, and yes I understand that interleaving is hard between products because few columns (except possible "date" and "general message") would necessarily line up.

Comment: see also [Alternates to Splunk](https://serverfault.com/q/62687/2321)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternatives to Splunk?](https://serverfault.com/questions/62687/alternatives-to-splunk)

Answer (score 1):

If you've got less than 500MB/day and are only monitoring a single server -- or don't mind paying, you're probably looking for [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAADFV).

Comment: thanks that looks interesting.  I was hoping for free tool I could install but of course this is a good answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question ([Is anybody using Splunk in a large-scale production environment?](https://serverfault.com/questions/23477/is-anybody-using-splunk-in-a-large-scale-production-environment) ) for other people's experiences with splunk and its competitors.

Answer (score 1):

Real men use grep and print their logs.  Makes good bedtime reading material. ;-)

Comment: heheh...so that makes me a real men :) something that filters out unneeded stuff, even if it's based on grep, would make my life easier

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [Lire](http://logreport.org/lire.html) of the [LogReport](http://logreport.org/) project. I used to work on that project, but it is Open Source, and allows you to analyze many different log files. There are binary [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=lire) and [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lire) packages at least, but likely for other platforms too.

Answer (score 0):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) might interest you.

Disclaimer: It's commercial and costs money beyond a certain amount of data per day.

But it does provide an interface for everything that you describe above.